# Rxandroid What's the difference between SubscribeOn and ObserveOn

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am just learning Rx-java and Rxandroid2 and I am just confused what is the major difference between in SubscribeOn and ObserveOn.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In case you find the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985270/8164116) full of jargons:

**tl;dr**

```
 Observable.just("Some string")                 
           .map(str -> str.length())              
           .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())   
           .map(length -> 2 * length)   
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .subscribe(---)
```

> Observe an observable... perform the map function in an **IO** thread (since we are `"subscribingOn"` that thread)... now switch to a **Computation Thread** and perform `map(length -> 2 * length)` function... and finally make sure you Observe the output on (`observeOn()`) **Main** thread.

**Anyway**,

`observeOn()` simply changes the thread of all operators further **Downstream**. People usually have this *misconception* that `observeOn` also acts as *upstream*, but it doesn't.

The below example will explain it better...

```
Observable.just("Some string")                  // UI
       .map(str -> str.length())               // UI
       .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())   // Changing the thread
       .map(length -> 2 * length)            // Computation
       .subscribe(---)                       // Computation
```

`subscribeOn()` only **influences** the thread which is going to be used when Observable is going to get subscribed to and it will stay on it downstream.

```
Observable.just("Some String")              // Computation
  .map(str -> str.length())                // Computation
  .map(length -> 2 * length)              // Computation
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // -- changing the thread
  .subscribe(number -> Log.d("", "Number " + number)); // Computation
```

> **Position does not matter (`subscribeOn()`**)

Why?
Because it *affects* only the time of subscription.

> **Methods that obey the contact with `subscribeOn`**

-> Basic example : `Observable.create`

All the work specified inside the `create` body will run on the thread specified in `subscribeOn`.

Another example: `Observable.just`,`Observable.from` or `Observable.range`

**Note:** All those methods accept values, so do not use blocking methods to create those values, as subscribeOn won't affect it.

If you want to use blocking functions, use

**`Observable.defer(() -> Obervable.just(blockingMenthod())));`**

> Important Fact:

subscribeOn does not work with `Subjects`

> Multiple `subscribeOn`:

If there are multiple instances of `subscribeOn` in the stream, only the **first** one has a practical effect.

> Subscribe & `subscribeOn`

People think that `subscribeOn` has something to do with `Observable.subscribe`, but it doesn't have anything special to do with it.
*It only affects the subscription phase*.

Source : Tomek Polański ([Medium](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a))

Comment: I'm confused, I thought I got it, but why does the answer below say that the position also matters in `subscribeOn`. So which one is true?

Comment: @Mon both the answers are somewhat correct, the thing is **position for `subscribeOn` matters if you are using multiple `subscribeOn` calls.** When it comes to a single call, the position **does not** matter.

Comment: if I do some UI work inside of the subscribe(), does that block my UI? I used subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) but I am not sure. Also Observable.defer() blocks main thread?

Comment: @Hilal in order to perform UI task, you have to swift to Main Thread and if you'll perform serious computation on Main Thread then it will freeze the UI that's why we usually perform our task in any thread other than `AndroidSchedulers.main()` and take the result to the Main thread to JUST update the UI.

Comment: @Hilal Talking about `Observable.defer()`, it has nothing to do with blocking the Main thread, that part is dependent upon the `Scheduler` you are using. The only thing  `.defer()` does is it does not create the Observable until the observer subscribes and defer create a fresh observable for each observer.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you so much for your answer. I have many questions about these things. For example if I do some UI work inside subscribe() method would that block the UI even though I subscribeOn Schedulers.io() and observeOn Schedulers.io() too? Thanks

Comment: @Hilal you won't be able to perform any UI task on `Schedulers.io()` you have to switch to **main** thread. Otherwise it will throw an exception!

Comment: @Dennis actually it does not throw an exception I think it works on Main Thread so subscribeOn() and observeOn() work for flatmap()  and map() functions since those are followed by them.

Answer (score 137):

SubscribeOn specify the Scheduler on which an Observable will operate.
ObserveOn specify the Scheduler on which an observer will observe this Observable.

So basically SubscribeOn is mostly subscribed (executed) on a background thread ( you do not want to block the UI thread while waiting for the observable) and also in ObserveOn you want to observe the result on a main thread...

If you are familiar with AsyncTask then SubscribeOn is similar to doInBackground method and ObserveOn to onPostExecute...

Answer (score 73):

## Summary

- Use `observeOn` to set threads for **callbacks** "further down the stream (below it)", such as code blocks inside `doOnNext` or `map`.
- Use `subscribeOn` to set threads for **initializations** "upstream (above it)", such as `doOnSubscribe`, `Observable.just` or `Observable.create`.
- Both methods can be called multiple times, with each call overwriting previous ones. **Position matters.**

---

Let's walk through this topic with an example: we want to find the length of the string "user1032613". This is not an easy task for computers, so it's only natural that we perform the intense calculation in a background thread, to avoid freezing the app.

## observeOn

We can call `observeOn` as many times as we like, and it controls which thread all **callbacks below it** will run. It's easy to use, and works just as you'd expect.

For example, we will show a progress bar on the main UI thread, then do intensive/blocking operations in another thread, then come back to the main UI thread to update the result:

```
    Observable.just("user1032613")

            .observeOn(mainThread) // set thread for operation 1
            .doOnNext {
                /* operation 1 */
                print("display progress bar")
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            .observeOn(backThread) // set thread for operation 2 and 3
            .map {
                /* operation 2 */
                print("calculating")
                Thread.sleep(5000)
                it.length
            }

            .doOnNext {
                /* operation 3 */
                print("finished calculating")
            }

            .observeOn(mainThread) // set thread for operation 4
            .doOnNext {
                /* operation 4 */
                print("hide progress bar and display result")
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                resultTextView.text = "There're $it characters!"
            }

            .subscribe()
```

In the above example, `/* operation 1 */` is ran in the `mainThread` because we set it using `observeOn(mainThread)` on the line right above it; then we switch to `backThread` by calling `observeOn` again, so `/* operation 2 */` will run there. Because we didn't change it before chaining `/* operation 3 */`, it will run in the back thread as well, just like `/* operation 2 */`; finally we call `observeOn(mainThread)` again, to make sure `/* operation 4 */` updates the UI from the main thread.

## subscribeOn

So we've learned `observeOn` sets threads for subsequent callbacks. What else are we missing? Well, the `Observable` itself, and its methods such as `just()`, `create()`, `subscribe()` and so on, are also code that needs to be executed. This is how objects are passed along the stream. We use `subscribeOn` to set threads for code related to `Observable` itself.

If we remove all the callbacks (controlled by `observeOn` discussed earlier), we are left with the "skeleton code" that will, by default, run on whichever thread the code is written in (probably main thread):

```
    Observable.just("user1032613")
            .observeOn(mainThread)
            .doOnNext {
            }
            .observeOn(backThread)
            .map {
            }
            .doOnNext {
            }
            .observeOn(mainThread)
            .doOnNext {
            }
            .subscribe()
```

If we aren't happy about this empty skeleton code running on main thread, we can use `subscribeOn` to change it. For example, maybe the first line `Observable.just("user1032613")` isn't as simple as creating a stream from my user name - maybe it's a string from the Internet, or perhaps you are using `doOnSubscribe` for some other intensive operations. In that case, you can call `subscribeOn(backThread)` to put some of the code in another thread.

#### Where to put `subscribeOn`

At the time of writing this answer, there are some misconceptions saying "only call it once", "position does not matter", and "if you call it multiple times, only the first time counts". After lots of researches and experiments, it turns out `subscribeOn` can be usefully called multiple times.

Because `Observable` uses [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (fancy name for "chaining methods one after another"), `subscribeOn` is applied in reverse order. Therefore, this method sets the thread for **code above it**, exactly the opposite of `observeOn`.

We can experiment this using `doOnSubscribe` method. This method is triggered on the subscription event, and it runs on the thread set by `subscribeOn`:

```
    Observable.just("user1032613")
            .doOnSubscribe {
                print("#3 running on main thread")
            }
            .subscribeOn(mainThread) // set thread for #3 and just()
            .doOnNext {
            }
            .map {
            }
            .doOnSubscribe {
                print("#2 running on back thread")
            }
            .doOnNext {
            }
            .subscribeOn(backThread) // set thread for #2 above
            .doOnNext {
            }
            .doOnSubscribe {
                print("#1 running on default thread")
            }
            .subscribe()
```

It might be easier to follow the logic, if you read the above example *from bottom to top*, just like how Builder Pattern executes the code.

In this example, the first line `Observable.just("user1032613")` is run in the same thread as `print("#3")` because there are no more `subscribeOn` in-between them. This creates the illusion of "only the first call matters" for people who only care about code inside `just()` or `create()`. This [quickly falls apart once you start doing more](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5459).

---

#### Footnote:

Threads and `print()` functions in the examples are defined, for brevity, as follows:

```
val mainThread = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
val backThread = Schedulers.computation()
private fun print(msg: String) = Log.i("", "${Thread.currentThread().name}: $msg")
```

Comment: I was the one who mentioned that "`subscribeOn()` works only once" in my answer(of the same question). Looking at your explanation seems like it does make sense. Can I use a bit of your explanation to update my answer?

Comment: thanks. a follow up question, if `observeOn` controls code *below* it, and `subscribeOn` controls code *above* it, which thread would a code block follow if it has `observeOn` above it and `subscribeOn` below it? Sorry just a bit confused

Comment: @Mon `subscribeOn` sets thread for the framework "skeleton" itself, and `observeOn` sets thread for the callback functions/code blocks. They are not controlling the same thing. In your case, a "code block" runs on whichever thread `observeOn` set it to be.

Comment: Great response with example code. For completeness, can you add in code in `subscribe()` and explain which thread it runs on and how `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` affect it?

Comment: this is not the behavior i see for rxjava  3

Answer (score 22):

If someone finds rx java description hard to understand (as me for example), here is pure java explanation:

#### subscribeOn()

```java
Observable.just("something")
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .subscribe(...);
```

Is equivalent of:

```java
Observable observable = Observable.just("something");
new Thread(() -> observable.subscribe(...)).start();
```

Because `Observable` emits values on `subscribe()` and here `subscribe()` goes in the separate thread, the values are also emitted in the same thread as `subscribe()`. This is why it works "upstream" (influences the thread for the previous operations) and "downstream".

#### observeOn()

```java
Observable.just("something")
  .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .subscribe(...);
```

Is equivalent of:

```java
Observable observable = Observable.just("something")
  .subscribe(it -> new Thread(() -> ...).start());
```

Here `Observable` emits values in the main thread, only the listener method is executed in the separate thread.

Answer (score 4):

When you subscribe to an observable, a flow starts that works its way up to the top of chain and then back down again. The subscribe part is relevant to the upward chaining and the observe part is relevant to the downward chaining.

Once the top of the chain is reached, the subscription phase has essentially completed. Events start to be emitted and the downward chain of maps, filters etc are invoked.

SubscribeOn influences **subscription** calls above its placement, for example doOnSubscribe.

ObserveOn influences **observation** calls below its placement, for example, doOnNext, map, flatmap etc.

Both will change the thread that is used to continue the flow either upward or downward.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class SubscribeVsObserveOn {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Ordinal 0: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Observable
            .just("a regular string.")
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable ->
                System.out.println("Ordinal 2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(s ->
                System.out.println("Ordinal 3: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .map(s -> s)
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable ->
                System.out.println("Ordinal 1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(s ->
                System.out.println("Ordinal 4: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .map(s -> s)
            .subscribe(s -> latch.countDown());

        latch.await();
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Ordinal 0: main
Ordinal 1: RxNewThreadScheduler-1
Ordinal 2: RxNewThreadScheduler-2
Ordinal 3: RxNewThreadScheduler-3
Ordinal 4: RxNewThreadScheduler-4
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is nothing new, I just want to clarify a little bit more.

1. Let's assume that we have two threads.

   ```
    val pool1 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool { runnable -> Thread(runnable, "Thread 1") }
    val pool2 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool { runnable -> Thread(runnable, "Thread 2") }
   ```

2. As the answers described, `observeOn` will set `Downstream`, and `subscribeOn` will set `Upstream`. But what if both of them was used? For check this, I added logs line by line.

   ```
   Observable.just("what if use both")
    .doOnSubscribe { Log.d("Thread", "both, doOnSubscribe A " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .doOnNext { Log.d("Thread", "both, doOnNext A " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .map {
        Log.d("Thread", "both, map A " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        it + " A"
    }

    // observeOn
    .observeOn(Schedulers.from(pool1)) 

    .doOnSubscribe { Log.d("Thread", "both, doOnSubscribe B " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .doOnNext { Log.d("Thread", "both, doOnNext B " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .map {
        Log.d("Thread", "both, map B " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        it + " B"
    }

    // subscribeOn
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(pool2)) 

    .doOnSubscribe { Log.d("Thread", "both, doOnSubscribe C " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .doOnNext { Log.d("Thread", "both, doOnNext C " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .map {
       Log.d("Thread", "both, map C " + Thread.currentThread().name)
       it + " C"
     }

    // observeOn main
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext { Log.d("Thread", "main " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
    .subscribe(
        { result -> Log.d("Thread", "main subscribe " + Thread.currentThread().name)}
        , { error -> {} }
        )
   ```

The result is:

```
both, doOnSubscribe C main
both, doOnSubscribe A Thread 2
both, doOnSubscribe B Thread 2

both, doOnNext A Thread 2
both, map A Thread 2

both, doOnNext B Thread 1
both, map B Thread 1

both, doOnNext C Thread 1
both, map C Thread 1

main main
main subscribe main
result: what if use both A B C
```

As you can see, `doOnSubscribe` called first, from bottom to top. That means `subscribe` has priority over other operators, so the first thread which handles first code was **Thread 2**.

And then other operators was called, line by line. After `observeOn`, thread was changed to `Thread 1`. Then, just before calling `subscribe`, `observeOn` was called again, for change thread to main thread. (Don't care about AndroidSchedulers, it is just a kind of scheduler)

**TL;DR;**

- First path, `subscribeOn` called first, from bottom to top.
- Second path, `observeOn` called, from top to bottom, along with other codes.
- Behavior was same on both RxJava2 and RxJava3

Comment: "`doOnSubscribe` called first, from bottom to top." -> the `doOnSubscribe` output you show is `C -> A -> B`. But if "bottom to top" is accurate shouldn't the output be `C -> B -> A` since that's the bottom-to-top order in the code?