# Will the Observable stop emitting midway in this scenario due to being garbage collected?

Tags: java, kotlin, garbage-collection, rx-java2

I was wondering if the observable is eligible to be garbage collected in this scenario:

```
fun getObservable() = Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    getObservable().subscribe { println(it) }

    //Just to be able to observe the output.
    Thread.sleep(20*1000)
}
```

It doesn't stop emitting. But I can't use it to be sure that it will not be GC'd after some time since it may just be that GC isn't triggering in this short span.

My guess is that it should be GC'd. We don't have a reference to the `Observable` returned from the `getObservable()` function since we can't access it anymore. Calling the function again will give a different new `Observable`. Since we can't reach the `Observable` itself, the rest of the objects are also unreachable. So, I think all of this can be garbage collected at any random time.

Some of my code in an Android App uses somewhat similar code. And it is an `Observable` that I hope will last as long as the `Application`. Since, GC will collect any garbage, I don't want my `Observable` to be GC'd in the middle of my app. So, please keep that in mind that I'm not looking for answers telling me whether it will be GC'd or not. What I care about is whether it can be GC'd.

Thank you for taking out your time to help me.

EDIT: To make the context clearer, here's the basic idea of the concerned code as I use it in my app.

Repository.kt:

```
interface Repository {

    //Other code.

    fun getUserPrefs(): Flowable<UserPreference>
}
```

MyViewModel.kt:

```
class MyViewModel(private val repository: Repository): ViewModel() {

    init {
        repository.getUserPrefs()
            .subscribe { //Code with UI state side effects }
    }
}
```

In my app, Repository's implementation will be a singleton.For those not familiar with Android, just know that ViewModel's can last for pretty long time. It's work is basically to be responsible for managing UI state.

Comment: I don't know the specific implementation details, but in order for the `Observable` to receive emitted items, the emitter needs to keep a reference to it, so as long as the emitter is not garbage collected, the `Observable` won't be garbage collected as well.

Comment: @user2340612 Thank you. It makes sense now. I'll wait for more answers just to be sure. But thank you very much. BTW I have mostly used C++ till 6-8 months ago. I'm a bit experienced with Java and Kotlin. I am productive in them but once in a while, I find myself stumped about these things. I don't have a solid knowledge about GC. Can you recommend any sources to help me give more clarity in this matter?

Comment: I read [this blog post](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/) that was really interesting for me

Comment: Yet another “will the garbage collector break this program” question… **No** the garbage collector is there, so the programmer can stop worrying about memory, not to have new worries about the garbage collector. There wouldn’t be the slightest sense in adding a garbage collector that breaks programs by collecting objects which are still in use. Unless the documentation of `subscribe` says explicitly to use some kind of *weak* references to allow the object to get collected (which wouldn’t make much sense either, but there are APIs doing such nonsensical things).

Comment: @Holger I had this doubt because as I mentioned, I'm relatively new to garbage collected languages. I understand that an ideal GC shouldn't get in the way of a programmer but I didn't know that in real life also, such issues don't happen. I was just trying to look out for cases in which issues might occur. Just to be safe. Your comment made me see the point though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2340612 A big thanks for the blog post! Now, things are clearer for me :)

Comment: @NightMare well, all garbage collectors are conservative in that, if in doubt, they will keep an object if they can’t prove whether it is unused. Even simple or naive gc algorithms like reference counting fulfill this property. In fact, even JVMs without a garbage collector fulfill this requirement. A garbage collector which reclaims an object that is still in use must be considered broken, as preventing precisely such scenarios is the very purpose of garbage collectors. In that regard it’s funny that almost every day, a new “will gc break the following code” question arrives at Stackoverflow…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after the `sleep` `main` exits and the emitting stops. If you try it with `Thread.sleep(1000)` you'll see that it only outputs

```
0
1
```

The reason for this is that your program terminates.

What you want here might be `blockingSubscribe`:

```
getObservable().blockingSubscribe { println(it) }
```

which will only return once the `Observable` is finished.

Note that you can subscribe on 3 types of events: `onNext`, `onError` and `onComplete`:

```
getObservable().blockingSubscribe({
    println(it)
}, {
    throw it
}, {
    println("finished")
})
```

Subscribing to all 3 will not change the fact that the subscriber runs out of scope so you'll still need to use `blockingSubscribe`. If you want to offload work between threads you can use `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`:

```
getObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .blockingSubscribe {
            println(it)
        }
```

You can read more about these [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984730/rxandroid-whats-the-difference-between-subscribeon-and-observeon).

**About garbage collection**:

The Java garbage collector is intelligent enough to reclaim resources which have references to each other but are not referenced by the so called "root reference":

```
 (Root reference)

 (obj0) --> (obj1)
  \          /
   \        /
    \      /
    (obj2)

^^^--- obj0, 1 and 2 are eligible for garbage collection
```

So why does your `Observable` keep running despite it being detached from other objects? The answer is that there are multiple types of "root" references in Java:

- Local variables
- Active Java threads
- Static variables
- JNI References

In your case when you call `subscribe` on your `Observable` it offloads work to RxJava-s threads which are "root" references in themselves so even if you don't have a reference of any of those objects they will still keep running ad infinitum or until the `Thread`s terminate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The way I see it is that calling `subscribe()` doesn't wait for the thread used by the `Observable` to finish while calling `blockingSubscribe()` waits for it. In my situation, the `Observable` will last for a significant chunk of time of my application. The issue is not whether the `Observable` will get to finish. It is whether it will be garbage collected before my application finishes with the application still depending on it. So, for the purposes of this question assume that the program will run for a long time(such that GC may run).

Comment: How do they depend on your `Observable`? Can you show us some more code?

Comment: I edited the question to add the details. If they're insufficient, please tell me.

Comment: Cool, now I understand your problem. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation is simply brilliant!! This makes it all crystal clear. I really hope you've a nice day ahead. Cheers :)

Comment: The sentence "The Java garbage collector is intelligent enough to reclaim resources which have references to each other but not to the so called "root reference":" is wrong. It does not matter what the to be reclaimed resource refers *to*; what matter is what they're referred *from*. Kept are all objects transitively referred from a root reference (= reachable from root).