# Can we Avoid Subscribe() from blocking in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am learning RxJava and created code

**Using this class to create a list of random Ints**

```
 public class Sources {
    
        public List<Integer> randomIntegerList() throws InterruptedException {
    
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    
            return IntStream
                    .range(0, 99)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        }
    }
```

**Some random functions**

```
public class Methods {

    public boolean isEven(Integer integer) {
        if (integer % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Problem is here**

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoApplication().executeSingle();
    }


    private void executeSingle() {
        Single.create(emitter -> {

            List<Integer> list = null;
            try {

                list = new Sources()
                        .randomIntegerList();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }

            emitter.onSuccess(list);
        })
                .subscribe(
                        x -> {printData((List<Integer>) x);}
                );

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    private void printData(List<Integer> list) {
        list    .stream()
                .filter(y -> new Methods().isEven(y))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Finished** is printed after a delay of 4 seconds.. basically after subscribe executes its functionality, how can I make it non-blocking. what I want is that thread keep executing next lines and when printData() function is called that thread stop executing and execute printData() first.

Comment: Are you looking for `observeOn()`?

Comment: Google `subscribeOn`/`observeOn`.

Comment: @Progman no Idea, new to RxJava let me check that on Internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, an Observable executes on the same thread that declared the Observer and subscribed it. I have modified your example slightly (using rxJava 3) -

```
Observable<Integer> randIntegerObservable =
        Observable.create(
            emitter -> {
              List<Integer> integers = new Sources().randomIntegerList();
              for (Integer integer : integers) {
                emitter.onNext(integer);
              }
            });

    randIntegerObservable
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + i.toString()));
```

If you run above code you'll see output like

```
main - 0
main - 2
main - 4
main - 6
main - 8 ...
```

You can use `subscribeOn()` operator, which instructs the source to fire emissions on a specified Scheduler (separate thread)

Code after adding `subscribeOn()` -

```
Observable<Integer> randIntegerObservable =
        Observable.create(
            emitter -> {
              List<Integer> integers = new Sources().randomIntegerList();
              for (Integer integer : integers) {
                emitter.onNext(integer);
              }
            });

    randIntegerObservable
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
            i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + i.toString())
            );

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(6);
```

And output(don't forget to add sleep in the end else main thread will exit before output is printed) -

```
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 0
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 2
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 4
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 6
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 - 8 ..
```

Check [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html) documentation for various Schedulers available. You can also use `observeOn()` instead of `subscribeOn()`. There is subtle difference between `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn(), as` observeOn() can be used to switch different scheduler downstream. You can find more detail in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49555019/2478531)